# Variable injection from one function to another function directly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a C# Web API project. In that web API project there are many controllers to receive GET / POST requests. These controllers call functions which in turn call other functions spread through multiple classes. Flow at times can be at 20 plus places.

Program is already working. Now there is a change and for that I need to pass a variable received in API CONTROLLER to one of the function which is deep inside.

Now problem is I have to pass variable all through which will take a lot of rework.

Is there no way (like dependency injection, not sure though) by which I can pass a variable to a function which is deep inside DIRECTLY?

See image attached, I have to pass a variable received in WEB API to DOMAIN FLEX without passing variable to intermediaries?
[image]
Is it simply not possible?

Comment: I can think about a lot of dirty ways, but none that I'd implement in my code. I'd rewrite the full chain (maybe encapsulating the variable in an object with other variables, if it makes more sense).

Comment: As far as I understand your system consists of a few layers (Services, Application, Domain).Maybe instead of passing primitive variables throw all of these layers you could add it to the existing model(for example ViewModel) and pass the model betweens layer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe DI will help you much because at the time your controller receives the value you want to pass through, the DI would have already instantiated all lower level dependencies. This seems to hold for `.net core` as well as *"classic"* `asp.net`

Here we're arriving at the dirty hack territory. One way to achieve what you are after will be to inspect [`HttpContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8) directly from your `Domain Flex` and fetch your parameter by hand (or with some sort of a helper method). You could potentially make it a specialised middleware, so have a look at the [request pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) and see if making a custom handler could help you there.

But doing this will definitely violate so many design principles that you will need a compelling reason to do so.